# switch, procuve 2510, error: OS TFTP in prgrs, SNMP denied

Tags: switch, hp-procurve

I cannot reboot 2510-24 then I get this message:
OS TFTP in prgrs, SNMP denied

Smart as I am I just started a new TFTP download of latest firmware, but that is a no-go since another download is in progress... well, there is not. But the switch say so.

Got a whole lot of 2510-24 with Q_11_17.swi installed. 3-4 of them report that a download is in progress even though there is not.

Can I kill it somehow? Without having to look them up and manually unplug power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a 'kill' command. I used it and it worked.

> kill                  Kill other active console, telnet, or ssh
>   sessions.

An old list of commands can be found here (probably outdated):
http://evilrouters.net/2010/04/06/hidden-procurve-commands/